# Android - Scanning Wi-Fi every 3-4 second

Tags: java, android, multithreading, wifi, rssi

i'm developing an app in which i want to obtain the SSID and the signal strength of all the available Wifi networks. The problem is that when I connect the phone to a network only this one shows changes in signal strenght. The other networks show changes rarely (after 10 seconds).
This is the class that I've created to get Wifi informations:

```
class Wifi {
    Context cxt=null;
    public  Wifi(Context c){
        this.cxt=c;
    }

    public HashMap<String,Integer> getWifiStrength(){
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) cxt.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    // Level of a Scan Result
        List<ScanResult> wifiList = wifiManager.getScanResults();

        HashMap<String, Integer> wireless=new HashMap<String, Integer>();

   for(int i=0; i< wifiList.size() ;i++) {
        ScanResult scanResult= wifiList.get(i);
        //int level = WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(scanResult.level, 500);
        int level = wifiList.get(i).level;

        String SSID = scanResult.SSID;
        wireless.put(SSID,level);
    }
        return wireless;
    }



}
```

This is what I do in my MainActivity:

```
final TextView wifi = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtWIFI);

final Wifi LocalWireless = new Wifi(this.getApplicationContext());

    Thread t = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (!isInterrupted()) {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                HashMap<String, Integer> wireless = LocalWireless.getWifiStrength();
                                 wifi.setText("");

                                for (String key : wireless.keySet()) {
                                    wifi.append(key + " " +wireless.get(key)+"\n");
                                }


                            }
                        });
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: " The problem is that when I connect the phone to a network only this one shows changes in signal strenght. " Which is 'this' one??

Comment: I mean that if I connect to my home networks, its signal is updated every 3-4 seconds. The other signals are updated every 10-15 seconds

Comment: In general, if I'm not connected to any network the "list" is updated every 10seconds, instead of 3-4 seconds